# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'edad' at row 1

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy insertando valores a una tabla desde php, me sale el error de:      'Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'edad' at row 1', tengo todos los valores en la tabla de la bd bien, no sé porqué me sale esto, adicional a ello me sale otro error que dice que las variables están indefinidas, no entiendo por qué sale el error si todo está bien

```
    <!-- CÓDIGO HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="salud.svg" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="citas.php" method="post">
        <label for="">Nombre de la mascota</label>
        <input type="text" name="mascota" id="" placeholder="Sacha">
        <label for="">Edad</label>
        <input type="number" name="edad" id="">
        <label for="">¿Para cuando quieres la cita?</label>
       <input type="datetime" name="fecha" value="<?php $fecha_actual?>">
        <label for="">Tipo de mascota</label>
        <select name="tipo_mascota" id="">
            <option value="perro" select>Perro</option>
            <option value="gato">Gato</option>
        </select>
        <label for="">Raza</label>
        <input type="text" name="raza" id="">
        <label for="">¿Qué debomos saber acerca de tu mascota?</label>
        <textarea name="comentarios" id="" cols="30" rows="10" autofocus>"A mi mascota le gusta el agua caliente"</textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Agendar cita">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

//CÓDIGO PHP
include("conection.php");

```
$mascota = $_POST['mascota'];
$edad = $_POST['edad'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha']; 
$tipo = $_POST['tipo_mascota'];
$raza = $_POST['raza'];
$comentarios = $_POST['comentarios'];  

#Obtener valores de la fecha 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$fecha_actual=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
#PRUEBA Y FUNCIONA, PERO NO ES EL METODO QUE NOS SIRVE: echo "Fecha " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

#Insertar los datos a la BD
$inserta = "INSERT INTO citas (nombre_mascota, edad, fecha, tipo_mascota, raza, comentarios) VALUES ('$mascota', '$edad', '$fecha', '$tipo', '$raza', '$comentarios')";


$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $inserta) or die (mysqli_error($con)); 

if ($resultado) {
    echo "<script>alert('Datos insertados con exito'); window.location='/VET/citas.php'</script>";
}else {
    echo "<script>alert('Error, no se pudo hacer el registro'); window.history.go (-1);</script>";
}
mysqli_close($con);

//TABLA DE LA BD 'CITAS'
    create table citas (id_citas int auto_increment, nombre_mascota varchar(50), edad int (12), fecha timestamp, tipo_mascota varchar (25), raza varchar(50), comentarios varchar (50),
primary key (id_citas));
```

ADJUNTO IMAGENES DEL ERROR
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1. Si la edad es entero, no debes usar `''` en el `insert` 2. Los valores calculados no se almacenan, debes leer sobre normalización de base de datos. 3. No estás enviando ningún valor en edad.

Comment: AHORA ME SALE ESTO:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '', '', '', '')' at line 1.

Lo sé aún soy nuevo en esto, estoy aprendiendo, gracias

Comment: Estás eliminando mal las comillas simples y te queda una consulta incorrecta. Hazle debug, imprímela antes de ejecutarla o algo. Revisa cómo quedaría al reemplazar las variables por los valores correspondientes...

Comment: 1) Prueba haciendo hecho a todas las variables... Creo que no las esta recibiendo el citas.php, y ve luego de eso... si te muestra las variables...

Comment: El action de tu formulario es citas.php. Pero veo que los datos lo recibes en connection.php

Comment: no, los datos los recibe citas.php, el connection.php es lo que incluye la conexion

Comment: No, no las muestra, pero no entiendo porqué

Comment: Escribe un `var_dump($_POST);` en `citas.php` y dinos qué muestra. Puede que no estés llenando los `input` o que la referencia en el `action`  no sea la correcta. ¿El archivo `citas.php` está en la misma carpeta del archivo donde está el formulario?

Comment: Sí, si está en la misma carpeta
con el var_dump($_POST);
C:\wamp64\www\Vet\citas.php:14:
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Pues el `var_dump` indica que no están llegando datos en el `$_POST`, entonces, o estás buscando en el archivo equivocado, o no está permitido el método POST en tu entorno o simplemente no estás llenando los input. ¿Qué URL ves en el archivo donde está el formulario, podrías indicarnos cuál es?